# Mysql where clause on multiple fields which one might be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my products table, I have 2 columns: `price` and `discounted_price` in which `discounted_price` is null most of the time unless there is a promotion for that product:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------------+
| id | name               | price | discounted_price |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------------+
|  1 | test 1             | 79.00 |       null       |
|  2 | test 2             | 50.00 |       45.00      |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------------+
```

The product with id of `2` is now on promotion and has `discounted_price`.
Now I want to query products to get products cheaper than 50 but in my query I need to check if `discounted_price` is `null` then look into `price`, otherwise look into `discounted_price`. What Google said is using:

```
$products = Product::where('coalesce(price, discounted_price) <= 50);
```

But it's not working :(

Comment: if you need to get cheaper than 50 and `null` also, then sub query is not enough?

Comment: In your example you're not closing the string, a `'` is missing at the end after `50`

Comment: @Pepper that's just typo in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative, you can use sub query, like this :

```
$q = 50;
$product = Product::where(function($query) use($q) {
      $query->where('discounted_price', '<=', $q)
            ->orWhere('price', '<=', $q)
   })
   ->get();
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it works, but still I don't know why `select * from products where coalesce(price, discounted_price) <= 50` is not working

Answer (score 1):

you can use `whereRaw`
instead of `where` or `where(DB::raw('coalesce(price, discounted_price') <= 50))`

also be carful to close your where by `'` character

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using where with clouser like this:

```
 $products = Product::where(function ($query)
        {
            $query->where('discounted_price',null)->where('price','<=',50);
        })->orWhere('discounted_price','<=',50)->get();
```

Comment: How about OrderBy?